# clojure app config files - spit output of pprint s-expression?

Tags: clojure

I need config files for a clojure application I'm building.  They should be easy enough for a user to modify in a text editor and convenient for my program to read.

I was thinking about serializing s-expressions and using spit to put it into a config file in the users home directory, but I want to pprint the data i spit so it looks a little more friendly to human eyes.

How can I spit the output of pprint in clojure?

Is my thought process correct on using serialized s-expressions as a config file in clojure?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you have a couple of options. First, pprint accepts an optional [writer](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.java.io/writer) as a second parameter or you can spit the result of [with-out-str](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/with-out-str): `(spit "f.txt" (with-out-str (pprint ..))`

I think serialized s-expressions are a reasonable choice as long as they are treated just as data.

Comment: perfect, works like a charm.  thanks for your help.   

`(spit (clojure.java.io/file (System/getProperty "user.home") "/.jdbc/connections" ) (with-out-str (pprint connections) ) )`